# Vue.js add multiple active class in v-for cicle

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have some `li` elements in a `v-for` cicle. I need to select more then one at the same time and, if already selected, remove `active` class.

My script works if I select the items in order: from first to last (to select items), from last to first (to deselect items). Please help me.

```js
var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  data: {
    tags: ['tag-1', 'tag-2', 'tag-3', 'tag-4'],
    activeTag: [],
  },
  methods: {
    onTagClick: function(i) {
      if ( this.activeTag.includes(i) ) {
        console.log('Delete');
        const index = this.activeTag.indexOf(i);
        if ( index > -1 ) {
            this.activeTag.splice(index, 1);
        }
      } else {          
        console.log('Add');          
        this.activeTag.push(i);
      }
      console.log(`activeTag[i]: ${this.activeTag}`);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

a {
color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li.active>a{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="example-1">
  <ul v-if="tags">
    <li v-for="(tag, i) in tags" :key="i" :class="{active: activeTag[i] === i}">
        <a @click="onTagClick(i)"  href="javascript:void(0)">{{ tag }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, did my answer helped somehow ?

Comment: Hi @kissu, I used Vinicius code and your advice to map the array. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

What do you think about this solution?
It's the shortest way to achive the same result.

```js
var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  data: {
    tags: [{tag:'tag-1', active: false},{tag:'tag-2', active: false}, {tag:'tag-3', active: false}, {tag:'tag-4', active: false} ],
    
  },
  methods: {
    onTagClick: function(i) {
       this.tags[i].active = !this.tags[i].active ;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

a {
color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li.active>a{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="example-1">
  <ul v-if="tags">
    <li v-for="(obj, i) in tags" :key="i" :class="{active: obj.active}" >
        <a @click="onTagClick(i)"  href="javascript:void(0)">{{ obj.tag }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### template

```
<li v-for="(tag, index) in tags" :key="index" :class="{active: tag.active}">
    <a href="#" @click.prevent="tag.active = !tag.active">{{ tag.name }}</a>
</li>
```

#### Script

```
  computed: {
    checked(){ return this.tags.filter(tag => tag.active).map(tag => tag.name)}
  },
  data() {
    return {
      tags: [
        {name:'tag-1', active: false},
        {name:'tag-2', active: false},
        {name:'tag-3', active: false},
        {name:'tag-4', active: false}
      ]
    }
  }
```

#### Complete sample. [Check this out](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eyJBcHAudnVlIjoiPHRlbXBsYXRlPlxuICA8dWwgdi1pZj1cInRhZ3NcIj5cbiAgICA8bGkgdi1mb3I9XCIodGFnLCBpbmRleCkgaW4gdGFnc1wiIDprZXk9XCJpbmRleFwiIDpjbGFzcz1cInthY3RpdmU6IHRhZy5hY3RpdmV9XCI+XG4gICAgICA8YSBocmVmPVwiI1wiIEBjbGljay5wcmV2ZW50PVwidGFnLmFjdGl2ZSA9ICF0YWcuYWN0aXZlXCI+e3sgdGFnLm5hbWUgfX08L2E+XG4gICAgPC9saT5cbiAgPC91bD5cbiAgPGRpdj5cbiAgICB7e2NoZWNrZWR9fVxuICA8L2Rpdj5cbjwvdGVtcGxhdGU+XG5cbjxzY3JpcHQ+XG5pbXBvcnQgeyBkZWZpbmVDb21wb25lbnQgfSBmcm9tIFwidnVlXCI7XG5leHBvcnQgZGVmYXVsdCBkZWZpbmVDb21wb25lbnQoe1xuICBjb21wdXRlZDoge1xuICAgIGNoZWNrZWQoKXsgcmV0dXJuIHRoaXMudGFncy5maWx0ZXIodGFnID0+IHRhZy5hY3RpdmUpLm1hcCh0YWcgPT4gdGFnLm5hbWUpfVxuICB9LFxuICBkYXRhKCkge1xuICAgIHJldHVybiB7XG4gICAgICB0YWdzOiBbXG4gICAgICAgIHtuYW1lOid0YWctMScsIGFjdGl2ZTogZmFsc2V9LFxuICAgICAgICB7bmFtZTondGFnLTInLCBhY3RpdmU6IGZhbHNlfSxcbiAgICAgICAge25hbWU6J3RhZy0zJywgYWN0aXZlOiBmYWxzZX0sXG4gICAgICAgIHtuYW1lOid0YWctNCcsIGFjdGl2ZTogZmFsc2V9XG4gICAgICBdXG4gICAgfVxuICB9XG59KTtcbjwvc2NyaXB0PlxuPHN0eWxlPlxubGkge1xuICBkaXNwbGF5OiBpbmxpbmUtYmxvY2s7XG4gIHBhZGRpbmc6IDhweCAxMHB4O1xuICBtYXJnaW4tcmlnaHQ6IDAuNXJlbTtcbn1cblxuYSB7XG5jb2xvcjogIzAwMDtcbiAgdGV4dC1kZWNvcmF0aW9uOiBub25lO1xufVxubGkuYWN0aXZlPmF7XG4gIGNvbG9yOiByZWQ7XG59XG48L3N0eWxlPiJ9)

```js
<template>
  <ul v-if="tags">
    <li v-for="(tag, index) in tags" :key="index" :class="{active: tag.active}">
      <a href="#" @click.prevent="tag.active = !tag.active">{{ tag.name }}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    {{checked}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
export default defineComponent({
  computed: {
    checked(){ return this.tags.filter(tag => tag.active).map(tag => tag.name)}
  },
  data() {
    return {
      tags: [
        {name:'tag-1', active: false},
        {name:'tag-2', active: false},
        {name:'tag-3', active: false},
        {name:'tag-4', active: false}
      ]
    }
  }
});
</script>
<style>
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

a {
color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li.active>a{
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I cannot change data structure

Comment: @riky1 why can't you change the data structure ? I don't see any reason of it not being feasable.

Comment: I get data from DB and I have that in `props`. I put values in `data()` only for the example

Comment: You can totally get those values from a DB and _massage_ it. Check my updated answer. Props or data do not make any difference, it's still data that you can change in your component, not a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution

```
<template>
  <div>
    <span
      v-for="element in array"
      :key="element.id"
      :class="{ red: element.active }"
      @click="toggleSelection(element)"
    >
      {{ element.label }}
    </span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      array: [
        { id: 1, label: 'tag1', active: false },
        { id: 2, label: 'tag2', active: false },
        { id: 3, label: 'tag3', active: false },
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleSelection(element) {
      const selectedElementIndex = this.array.findIndex((item) => item.id === element.id)
      this.array[selectedElementIndex].active = !this.array[selectedElementIndex].active
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.red {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

---

I still highly recommend updating your array and giving it a real unique ID, rather than passing `index` to the `:key`, which is actually doing the opposite of what it's supposed to do.

To achieve a friendly array with nice keys, you can use this on your current `tags`:

```js
this.array = tags.map((tag, index) => ({id: index, label: tag, active: false}))
```

You could call this method once you have pulled the data from an API (in an `async created()` hook), change it then insert it into your template, hence modify the structure to a more friendly format.